# IMO number theory easy question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is:
Prove that for all positive integers n, the fraction $\frac{21n+4}{14n+3}$ is irreducible.

Then I saw that many said: "Since $2(21n+4) - 3(14n+3) = -1$ the result follows". And I am not really able to see why this is the case. Can you please explain it to me?
Thanks.

Comment: Eucledian Algorithm. Look it up.

Comment: I know the Euclidean Algorithm. But I get that: $gcd(21n+4,14n+3) = gcd(7n+1, 14n+3) = ... = 1$.
I don't see why the result is so obvious from that equation.

Comment: If the gcd of the two expressions is $d$, then from that equation, $d|1$ so $d = 1$.

Comment: loooooooool I see

Comment: You ask why it follows from that equation: it's an application of [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity): The numbers of the form $ax+by$ (where $a,b,x,y\in\Bbb Z$) are all multiples of $\gcd(x,y)$, or equivalently $\gcd(a,b)$ and that equation implies the gcd is $\gcd(3,-2)=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there exists an integer $x > 1$ that divides both $21n+4$ and $14n+3$.

Then clearly $x$ divides $3(14n+3)-2(21n+4)=1$

This is clearly a contradiction since $x > 1$.

Comment: Thanks, that's really clear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k$ be a common factor, greater than zero, of both the numerator and the denominator. Let 
$$21n+4=Ak$$
and 
$$13n+3=Bk$$
Then 
$$k(3B-2A)=3Bk-2Ak=(42n+9)-(42n+8)=1$$
The first expression is divisible by $k$, so $(21n + 4, 14n + 3) = 1$, and the fraction is not reducible.

Comment: I'm really suspicious that you just copied that from AoPS forum. :(

Comment: Nah, this is an easy problem. This is the first approach I thought of when I solved this some time ago (and yes, the solution is identical to the AoPS one).